# How to call these function into main program to print the values.?

Tags: python

I need help to call these functions into a main program using python. The following are 3 programs how to call them into main program to print the values?

```
Mass_in_gram=int(input("Enter Mass in grams :"))
def g_to_kg(Mass_in_gram):
    Mass_in_kg=(Mass_in_gram/1000)
    return Mass_in_kg
print(g_to_kg(Mass_in_gram))
```

```
Length_in_cm=int(input("Enter Length in centimeteres :"))
def cm_to_m(Length_in_cm):
    Length_in_m=(Length_in_cm/100)
    return Length_in_m
print(cm_to_m(Length_in_cm))
```

```
Time_in_min=int(input("Enter Time in minutes :"))
def min_to_sec(Time_in_min):
    Time_in_sec=(Time_in_min*60)
    return Time_in_sec
print(min_to_sec(Time_in_min))
```

Comment: Are these functions in the same file or a different file?

Comment: try importing the file they are implemented in and then do filename.function_name()

Comment: @DarryIG it is in a same file

Comment: if the codes are in 3 different .py files try to do import on main like `import weight` and if you want to use the function then you need to remove the input and the print from your files and after you do import you can use the functions like `weight.g_to_kg(3200)`. And if you want to use it directely u can do use `from weight import * ` if the file that contains  the function `g_to_kg()` is in weight.py

Comment: it would be better to put `input()` in function too - and then you can run them in any moment (after importing) and run them many time. Now `input() will be executed automatically at import and you can't control it. Or put `input()` in `if __name__ == "__main__":` to execute `input()` only when you run script directly but now when you import it.

Comment: @AnassABEA I didn't get that can u plz explain it in form of Python plz.

Comment: @WalterWhite can you provide the names of the python files (programs) you have used for each function ?

Comment: @AnassABEA thank you for your answer but someone also has answered with reference to python, so thank you.

Comment: @WalterWhite--actually if the functions are in the same file as you state, the answer is actually simpler than the one you accepted.  There's no need to place the functions in separate files or import the different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply import all the necessary files *(make sure they're in the same folder)*:

`g_to_kg.py`:

```
Mass_in_gram=int(input("Enter Mass in grams :"))
def g_to_kg(Mass_in_gram):
    Mass_in_kg=(Mass_in_gram/1000)
    return Mass_in_kg
print(g_to_kg(Mass_in_gram))
```

`cm_to_m.py`:

```
Length_in_cm=int(input("Enter Length in centimeteres :"))
def cm_to_m(Length_in_cm):
    Length_in_m=(Length_in_cm/100)
    return Length_in_m
print(cm_to_m(Length_in_cm))
```

`min_to_sec.py`:

```
Time_in_min=int(input("Enter Time in minutes :"))
def min_to_sec(Time_in_min):
    Time_in_sec=(Time_in_min*60)
    return Time_in_sec
print(min_to_sec(Time_in_min))
```

---

**`program.py`:**

```
import min_to_sec
import cm_to_m
import g_to_kg
```

**Output:**

```
Enter Time in minutes :3
180
Enter Length in centimeteres :4
0.04
Enter Mass in grams :5
0.005
```